# How to Sync yahoo contacts with android contacts?

Tags: android

I ve tried using Y Mail app to fetch yahoo contacts and it sync with android contacts. 
But I want yahoo conatcts to be synced with contacts using android account manaager.(ie, Email app).Please tell me how do i sync with android contacts?

Comment: I think this question should be moved to android.stackexchange.com